# Feedparser not parsing searched for description

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I'm trying to utilize RSS to get auto notifications for specific security vulnerabilities i may be concerned with. I have gotten it functional for searching for keywords in the title and url of feed entries, but it seems to ignore the rss description.

I've verified the description field exists within the feed (I originally started with summary in place of description before discovering this) but don't understand why its not working (relatively new to python). Is it possibly a sanitation issue, or am i missing something on how the search is performed?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import feedparser

#Keywords to search for in the rss feed


key_words = ['Chrome','Tomcat','linux','windows']

# get the urls we have seen prior

f = open('viewed_urls.txt', 'r')
urls = f.readlines()
urls = [url.rstrip() for url in urls]
f.close()

#Returns true if keyword is in string

def contains_wanted(in_str):
    for wrd in key_words:
        if wrd.lower() in in_str:
            return True
    return False

#Returns true if url result has not been seen before

def url_is_new(urlstr):
    # returns true if the url string does not exist
    # in the list of strings extracted from the text file
    if urlstr in urls:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#actual parsing phase

feed = feedparser.parse('https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/misc/nvd-rss.xml')
for key in feed["entries"]:
    title = key['title']
    url = key['links'][0]['href']
    description  = key['description']

#formats and outputs the specified rss fields

    if contains_wanted(title.lower()) and contains_wanted(description.lower()) and url_is_new(url):
        print('{} - {} - {}\n'.format(title, url, description))

#appends reoccurring rss feeds in the viewed_urls file
        with open('viewed_urls.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(title,url))
```

Comment: `contains_wanted(title.lower()) and contains_wanted(description.lower()) and url_is_new(url)` Are you sure this is supposed to be a conjunction?

Comment: Because if the title does not contain wanted word then the other expressions in this if statement are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

This helped. I was unaware of the conjunction logic but have resolved it. I omitted contains_wanted(title.lower()) since this was not necessary in the statement logic as contains_wanted(description.lower()) fulfills the title statements purpose as well as its own. and am getting proper output.

Thank you pbn.